# how to prohibit UIScrollview scrolling when move in specific area?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I put one `UIImageview` as subview in a `UIScrollview`. When I zoom in the image, I can scroll the image around. Can I disable the scrolling when I touch and moving in a rectangle area of the image?

I want to get information from `touchesBegan()` of customed `UIScrollview` and customed `UIImageview`, but I found that when there are scrolling, no `touchesBegan` is called in customed `UIImageview`.

Answer (score 0):

`yourScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;` for scroll to be enabled.

`yourScrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;` for scroll to be disabled.

Comment: Maybe I did not make the question clear. I don't know how to detect that the touch is in the specific area or not, because after the image was scaled bigger than the screen, touch event will cause scroll directly, without to call touchesBegan function. Then question is where to check the touch position and put the scrollEnabled code?